# Excel Create Hierarchy given level in order

Tags: excel, excel-formula, parent, hierarchy, vba

I have an order of unique Id's and the level of their indentation.  They are in order so the parent of the current ID is the ID of the one with 1 less than the current indent level (e.g. if the current indent level is 3, the parent ID will be the id of the first row above it with an indent level of 3-1=2 which is UniqueID=4 in this case).

Here is a sample of my data:
[image]

I want a new column with the parent UniqueID of the current UniqueID.

Thanks

Comment: By 'first row with an indent level of X' do you mean as in top down, unconditionally? 

Meaning if your indent level went top to bottom: 1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2. The last 2 in this sequence would have the parentID equal to the uniqueID of the first '1' in this sequence? Versus the 5th digit or 6th digit's uniqueId (3rd/4th '1' respectively).

Comment: Assuming the previous assumption is true, you should be able to use the following formula starting in cell D2, and extending down.

    =INDEX(B:B, MATCH(C1-1,C:C,0))

Comment: Yes Kris you're first statement is correct.

Comment: To your second comment, it's close but it doesn't work.  Here is what it is returning from D2 on: #VALUE!, #N/A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5,, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7 ...
Should be: nothing, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 14, 14, 4, 4, 18,

Comment: Wrap the formula in IFERROR to remove the #Value. EG: =IFERROR(INDEX(....), "") Also start at C2, not C1 for cell D2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I wrote a Visual Basic script that contains the following:

```
Function parent(r As Range) As Integer

curVal = r.Value
desiredCol = 2

parentFound = False

counter = 1
'loop through until parent is found or at beginning
Do Until CInt(r.Row) < 2 Or parentFound = True
    If r.Offset(-counter, 0).Value < curVal Then
        parentFound = True
        desiredRow = r.Offset(-counter, 0).Row
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
Loop

parent = r.Offset(-counter + 1, -1).Value

End Function
```

This searches for the first cell above in the column with a level below it, and takes the value of the ID to the left of it.